# Modify jquery $.get function response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used the `$.get` function in many cases in my project:

```
$.get(user, function (data) {
   // CODE
});
```

Now, i want to modify it to:

```
   $.get(user, function (data) {
         if (validate_data(data)){
             // CODE
         }
    });
```

but it is impossible to go to every single javascript file in project and modify all the instances. Is it possible to modify the `jquery.js` file instead to get the same result?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but I'd probably avoid it. Instead look for ajaxComplete kinda solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can handle data before success and use throw to stop script. Not the best solution but should works.

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(response, type){
    if (!validate_data(response)){
        throw "Stop!";
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: If `validate_data` returns true, the code in the original $.get function does not get fired.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about return.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to pull something by using

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(data) { ... } )
```

Comment: Dangerous to add that sort of validation code generically to all  Ajax requests. What about breaking other plugins that use Ajax?

Comment: @trueblueaussi that's true indeed. you would have to take care of the potential collateral damages by checking the nature of your data and the origin of your request

Comment: I don't want the same Success function for all my get requests, I just want to do a validation before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do so is to extend jQuery (not tested):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    get_validated: function(url, callback) {
        return $.get(url, function(data) {
            if(validateData(data)) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and then replace every occasion of `get` with `get_validated` with the command `replace in files` in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a callback function using ajaxComplete to the ajax request as below

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "MY GET URL" ) { //IF URL matches the one that you need
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
  xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

The only limitation of this trick is that you must have something in your call so that you can identify that it's get call of which you want to validate the response